# Automatic alternating image-text for blog list in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware6

I'm trying to build a new Layout for a Landing Page in Shopware 6.
It should show a list of blog articles with an image and a teaser text.
The image for the first blog article should be left, the next one right.
[image]

Of course, I can achieve this manually. But what happens when I decide to add another blog article somewhere in the middle, I would need to change the text and image boxes for all the following blog entries. This means a lot of work for the content creator.

I appreciate any input on how this can be solved.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a container which contains all the blog-entries (.blogItems in my example), you can just use straight CSS (with flex-box order https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items) to achieve this.

This example doesn't actually work/render (CSS is written in SCSS, and I am missing some classes/styling), but the general idea should work.

```css
.blogItems:nth-child(even) {
    .imgCol {
        order: 1;
    }
    .textCol {
        order: 2;
    }
}
.blogItems:nth-child(odd) {
    .imgCol {
        order: 2;
    }
    .textCol {
        order: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="blogItems">
    <div class="blogItem row">
        <div class="imgCol col-5">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="textCol col-7">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rutrum iaculis leo ac tristique. Integer a placerat elit.
                Phasellus fermentum lorem vel ipsum viverra bibendum. Suspendisse maximus magna et dolor lacinia aliquet.
                Ut euismod ornare luctus. Aenean porttitor id elit vel aliquam. Aenean id auctor odio</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blogItem row">
        <div class="imgCol col-5">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="textCol col-7">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rutrum iaculis leo ac tristique. Integer a placerat elit.
                Phasellus fermentum lorem vel ipsum viverra bibendum. Suspendisse maximus magna et dolor lacinia aliquet.
                Ut euismod ornare luctus. Aenean porttitor id elit vel aliquam. Aenean id auctor odio</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blogItem row">
        <div class="imgCol col-5">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="textCol col-7">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rutrum iaculis leo ac tristique. Integer a placerat elit.
                Phasellus fermentum lorem vel ipsum viverra bibendum. Suspendisse maximus magna et dolor lacinia aliquet.
                Ut euismod ornare luctus. Aenean porttitor id elit vel aliquam. Aenean id auctor odio</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blogItem row">
        <div class="imgCol col-5">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="textCol col-7">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rutrum iaculis leo ac tristique. Integer a placerat elit.
                Phasellus fermentum lorem vel ipsum viverra bibendum. Suspendisse maximus magna et dolor lacinia aliquet.
                Ut euismod ornare luctus. Aenean porttitor id elit vel aliquam. Aenean id auctor odio</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```